# Access element of list by variable name

Tags: python-3.x

How can I access a list element using the name of the list?

I would like to allow a user to edit the code in determine a single variable to be inputted into a function. For example:

```
blah = [1,2]
blah2 = 5

toBeChanged = "blah2"

def foo():  
     print(blah)

def changeVariable():
    globals()[toBeChanged] += 1

for time in range(5):  
    changeVariable()  
    simulate
```

This works for blah2 since it is a simple variable, however it will not work for blah[0] since it is part of a list. I've also tried placing my variables into a dictionary as other answers have suggested, but I still am unable to change list elements through a simple string.

Is there a way to do this that I am missing? Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect the result of `[1,2]+=1` to be?

Comment: This is why I am looking for the way to change a single element of the list. For example I want to change blah[0] by incrementing it by 1 not the entire list.

Comment: This whole notion seems like a bad idea. Use a dictionary and test the object type is the way to do what you want, but it seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Would you mind going into more detail as to why it is a bad idea? Thanks!

Comment: Because it is not natural Python code in this case. What if you pass a tuple or a set or a dict to this function? What is `set([1, 2])+=1`? What is `(1, 2)+=1`? Are you saying you want a function that supports a list and anything else that support `+=`? Float? String? You are writing inflexible code and it is probably to address a lack of understanding of the problem that you are looking at. The strong typing in Python is there for a reason.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you! I'll look for another method of addressing my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `globals()` and altering directly it would be much, much better to use a dictionary to store the variables you want the user to alter, and then manipulate that:

```
my_variables = {
    'blah': [1,2]
    'blah2': 5
}

toBeChanged = "blah2"

def foo():  
     print(my_variables['blah'])

def changeVariable():
    my_variables[toBeChanged] = my_variables.get(toBeChanged,0) + 1

for time in range(5):  
    changeVariable()
```

This has the added advantage that if a user enters a variable that doesn't exist a default is chosen, and doesn't override any variables that might be important for future execution.

Comment: This is almost what I would like, however when run I receive a type error, can only concatenate list (not int) to list. While the .get(toBeChanged,0) accesses the proper element, I cannot revalue it since its a function, is there a way around this? Thanks!